# Excel userform - not reading or writing to the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a new userform which writes your data to the spreadsheet and using a drop down will then load that data back into the form for you to edit and re-save. When I click save it will not write to the spreadsheet and when I pre-populate the spreadsheet it will not then load to the userform. I have the below code which works for a similar userform but will not work for the new one I am compiling. I get no error messages when running. What am I missing?

```
Dim NotNow As Boolean
Dim dropbuttonclicked As Boolean
Private Sub cmd_Submit_Click() 'Submit

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
 Sheet1.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
 emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ctl As Control
' inputs new project if no ref selected
If Me.cboSearch.Value = "" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo WithRef
        With ActiveSheet
            If .AutoFilterMode Then
                .ShowAllData
            End If
            End With
Else

' If a search is selected edit that line of data
    NotNow = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' unprotects the report
    On Error GoTo WithRef
        With ActiveSheet
            If .AutoFilterMode Then
                .ShowAllData
            End If
            End With
WithRef:
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
If Me.cboSearch.Value = "" Then
    n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
Else
    n = Application.Match(Me.cboSearch.Value, Range("A:A"), 0)
End If

On Error GoTo Contnow

'Transfer information

     Cells(n, 1).Value = Log_No.Value
     Cells(n, 2).Value = Statement.Value
     Cells(n, 3).Value = Raised_By.Value
     Cells(n, 4).Value = Format(Raised_Date.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
     Cells(n, 5).Value = Action.Value
     Cells(n, 6).Value = Act_Owner.Value
     Cells(n, 7).Value = Rel_Ph.Value
     Cells(n, 8).Value = Cat.Value
     Cells(n, 9).Value = Status.Value
     Cells(n, 10).Value = Pos_Neg.Value
     Cells(n, 11).Value = Format(Trans_Date.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
     Cells(n, 12).Value = Ref.Value


Contnow:
    ' clear data from the form
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "DTPicker" Then
    ctl.Value = ""
    ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
    ctl.Value = False
    End If
    Next ctl

    ' Save and return to normal mode
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Unload Me
    Project_LL_Form.Show vbModeless
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
Private Sub cmd_Close_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub cboSearch_Change()
If NotNow Then Exit Sub
'if ref is blank then clear data from form
If Me.cboSearch.Value = "" Then

    Unload Me
    Project_LL_Form.Show vbModeless

Else
' bring in data based on ref in REF range
vrange = "Log"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
n = Application.Match(Me.cboSearch.Value, Range("A:A"), 0)

On Error GoTo contkh

'Transfer information to the form
'Project Information transfer
     Log_No.Value = Cells(n, 1).Value
     Statement.Value = Cells(n, 2).Value
     Raised_By.Value = Cells(n, 3).Value
     Raised_Date.Value = Format(Cells(n, 4).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
     Action.Value = Cells(n, 5).Value
     Act_Owner.Value = Cells(n, 6).Value
     Rel_Ph.Value = Cells(n, 7).Value
     Cat.Value = Cells(n, 8).Value
     Status.Value = Cells(n, 9).Value
     Pos_Neg.Value = Cells(n, 10).Value
     Trans_Date.Value = Format(Cells(n, 11).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
     Ref.Value = Cells(n, 12).Value

contkh:
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where sre those "Log_No, Value Statement, Raised_By, Raised_Date, Action" variables defined? If they're names of UserForm controls then they must be preceeded by "Me."

Comment: The code actually worked fine, it was the userform that was corrupted.